# How to fix 'Remove property setter' build error?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a property in a model which has auto property getter and setter:

```
[DataMember]
public Collection<DTOObjects> CollectionName { get; set; }
```

I get the following error when building the solution:

> Microsoft.Usage : Change 'propertyname' to be read-only by removing the property setter.

However, when I remove the setter and run the code, an error occurs because it's trying to set the property! It appears it's asking me to remove the setter despite the fact it is being set somewhere in the code.

Has anyone else come accross this problem? What do I need to modify?

Comment: context? what does this property look like? is is a list by any chance?

Comment: It's a collection of DTO objects.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I'm going to guess this is a list/collection (or something similar), in which case yes - it is unusual to have a setter. A typical example might be:

```
private readonly List<Foo> items = new List<Foo>();
public List<Foo> Items { get { return items; } }
```

Most callers **should not** be trying to assign to that; they shouldn't *need* to - they can add/remove/enumerate/clear/etc the list without ever needing to assign it.

> an error occurs because it's trying to set the property

Then consider changing that code so that it *doesn't* try to set the property. It *should not need to* in virtually all cases.

Comment: Yes it is a collection. How do I include the data in the model if I don't set it?

Comment: @Theomax `obj.Items.Add(newItem)` or `obj.Items.AddRange(newItems)` - in most code you should never need to set a collection, except as an initializer / constructor.

Comment: also you can solve by removing **set** keyword after C# 6

`public Collection<DTOObjects> CollectionName { get; }`

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to initialize the `Collection` in the constructor...

```
public class Email
{
    public Email() 
    {
        To = new List<MailAddress>();
    }

    ....

    public List<MailAddress> To { get; }
}
```

Then just use .add in code:

```
   Email oEmail = new Email();
   oEmail.To.Add(new MailAddress("Foo@fighter.com", "Mr. Foo"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Just suppress it, right click the error and click suppress in code & an attribute will be added to the property.

Generally you shouldn't have a public set for collections as this allows the list to be replaced, however with objects that are created or deserialized at runtime sometimes the public setter is necessary.

Comment: which serializers require a setter? that is pretty unusual - I can't think of any off the top of my head (although: `XmlSerializer` has a bug: it is happy if it *doesn't have* a setter, but if there is a private settter it incorrectly tries to use it, and fails - removing the setter fixes that)

Comment: If you're using auto implemented properties, you do for the DataContractSerializer in WCF & also I think with Json.net if you are using auto implemented properties.

Comment: If you're using auto implemented properties, then there *is* a setter (always) - pretty sure DCS doesn't mind `private`.

Answer (score 0):

From the docs:

"You can suppress the warning if the property is part of a Data Transfer Object (DTO) class. Otherwise, do not suppress warnings from this rule."

If it's not part of a DTO:

"To fix a violation of this rule, make the property read-only. If the design requires it, add methods to clear and repopulate the collection."

The preferred manner of replacing a read-only collection property is to use the Clear and AddRange methods (or their equivalents).

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/code-quality/ca2227?view=vs-2019